# Procedimiento Almacenado para eliminar datos en tablas referenciadas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Necesito ayuda con un procedimiento almacenado que me permita eliminar un columna en la tabla `usuarios` y cuando se elimine esta columna eliminar todos los datos donde se utilice como primary key su `id`, la tabla que hereda de `usuarios` es `facturas` y esta factura tiene un detalle factura `det_factura` heredando la primary key de `facturas`.

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_eliminarusuario 
@iduser int
AS
BEGIN
DELETE det_facturas FROM facturas f, det_facturas d, usuarios u WHERE 
f.idfactura = d.idfactura and f.idusuario=u.idusuario
DELETE facturas FROM facturas f, usuarios u where f.idusuario=u.idusuario
DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE idusuario = @idusers
END
```

Este procedimiento me elimina todos los datos tanto en `facturas` como en `det_facturas` como podría solucionarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tendiendo muy bien la estructura que mencionas de la base de datos,
seria interesante que añadieras un mini diagrama ERM de tú BDD con sus relaciones de cada tabla.

Aunque si estas usando MySql, con el **Engine=InnoDB**
y lo que intentas eliminar son datos asociados de una FK(Foreign Key)
deberías configurar en cada relación FK la option de 'ON CASCADE'
en este caso seria:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
 id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT,
  parent_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES parent(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial de Mysql sobre 'ON CASCADE': [Aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sería interesante saber si las claves foraneas que hacen referencia a la tabla usuarios tienen la opción cascade. De ser así simplemente haces un delete a la tabla usuarios y automáticamente eliminas todos los registros de las otras tablas que hacen referencia a ella.

De lo contrario lo podría hacer por medio de subconsulta, por ejemplo:

```
DELETE FROM det_facturas WHERE idfactura = (
SELECT id FROM facturas INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = factura.idusuario);

DELETE FROM facturas WHERE idusuario = (SELECT id usuario WHERE id = ?);

DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?
```

Según la necesidad, lo puedes adicionar a una función o procedimiento.